# How to enable external build in Android Studio permanently?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

If I start Android Studio and want to run a project, I get the following error:

> Deprecated make implementation
>            Old implementation of "Make" feature is enabled for this project.
>            It has been deprecated and will be removed soon.
>            Please enable newer 'external build' feature in Settings | Compiler.

After I enabled the external build feature everything is working fine. But after I restart Android Studio I get the same error. I tried the "Apply" and "OK" button in the settings. But nothing is storing it permanently. 
How can I set this configuration for permanent use?

**EDIT:**
I tried to figure out what will be changed in the configuration files, but there was nothing changed concerning the compiler settings.

Comment: This was a "fix" implemented in a previous version of Android Studio for projects using Ant build (instead of Gradle). It seems that they hardcoded the "fix" since, as you mentioned, the config files are no longer changed for this setting. Not sure if there will be a fix for this as they are force-feeding us Gradle (which if you check SO, is buggy as hell). May need to go back to IntellJ for Ant projects.

Comment: I received an update today. Unfortunately it is not able to solve the issue.

Comment: It does not save "Confirm Exit"/"Don't ask me again" setting also. I thought it related to MacSandbox/Java access mode problems, have not investigated through.

Comment: Google says: That this issue is already fixed and will be provided in version 0.2.7 https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update is now available. To fix this issue just update to the latest version of Android Studio 0.2.7 or higher.